# Running JAVA in Cygwin through bash script

Tags: bash, java, cygwin

I've been encountering a problem with cygwin where I cannot run a jar file with an error that the file cannot be found.

If it were easier i would "translate" the java source in bash, but unfortunately, due to the functionality implemented, there are some quite significant obstacles to achieve this, so I'd have to use the jar file.

Now, I've done a fair amount of research on my part to figure out how to do this, however, I couldn't succeed, and it is mandatory that i use cygwin.

Here's what I'm trying to essentially do:

```
lockfile="$specialfolder/$passedargument.lock
java -jar `cygpath -w ./cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder/javafile.jar -joption cygpath -w $lockfile`
```

i also tried with double back-ticks, as follows:

```
pathtooutfile="${some_other_vars}/${that}_${work}.out"
java -jar `cygpath -w ./cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder/javafile.jar` -joption `cygpath -w $lockfile`
```

i also tried using the $JAVA_HOME env var but that did not work as well. It is important to mention that the variables being called in **lockfile** var are defined as follows:

```
 homedir= "/cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder"
 specialfolder= "$homedir/foler/$passedargument"
 passedargument= $1 ###argument passed with execution of bash script
 lockfile= "$specialfolder/$passedargument"
```

The error i keep getting is this: *Error: Unable to access jarfile*
I have modified usage rights to 777 and that didn't work either. It might also be important to mention that **-joption** is either **-aquire** or **-release** corresponding to the **lockfile** since one of the things the jar does is manage multiple script executions through a lock file.
I'm somewhat stuck so, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. I think that this might be more of a cygwin issue.

Comment: What does `cygpath -w ./cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder/javafile.jar` return if you run it on its own. (Please add the output to your question, not as a comment).

Comment: always Error: Unable to access jarfile

Comment: So the command, `cygpath -w ./cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder/javafile.jar` on its own, with nothing else, gives you that error?  Can you copy and paste you typing that command in and the output? In the question.  You are using `c` or `d` (or something) in place of `driveletter`, rather than the word `driveletter`?

Comment: it gives me the path to the file in unix format, and yes i am using an actual drive letter like "d" for example

Comment: I can't express enough how much more useful it would be for you to edit your original question using [this link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/268855/edit) and adding the output from the command directly into the question, because if the `cygpath` command is returning the UNIX format, it's not working.

Comment: cygpath and all forms of pathing to file in general is easily fixable and that is not the main issue here. I have been experimenting with different options  for pathing to the file and none of them ever worked, not even in cmd. On the other hand the same implementation, works perfectly on other other machines(regardless of java version). I have compared the problematic env with the others and there are no differences.

Comment: Sorry, since you continue to resist adding any useful diagnostic information to your question, you prevent people helping.  I'll just go answer someone elses question (I use `cygpath` myself in plenty of situations, but since we don't know what it's outputting in your instance, *we can't help*).

Comment: 1.ignore the existence of cygpath in this scenario; 2. cd to folder where the jar file is located; 3. type: java -jar <nameofjavafile>; 4. observe  Error: Unable to access jarfile; 5.cygpath was NEVER the problem

Comment: Then edit your question with that detail, because right now, that's not what your question is asking.

Comment: Java doesn't understand Cygwin paths.

Answer (score 0):

If your expression

```
`cygpath -w ./cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder/javafile.jar`
```

has embedded blanks, you should put double-quotes around it so that the result is passed to Java as a single token.  It can help to understand the expressions and results if you turn on the shell trace, e.g., `set -x`.

Further reading:

- [cygpath — Convert Unix and Windows format paths, or output system path information](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html)
- [Making Cygwin and Windows cooperate](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/08/29/making-cygwin-and-windows-cooperate/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `cygpath -w -a .....`

The `-a` returns absolute paths.

e.g.

```
$ cygpath -w ./screenshot.jpg
screenshot.jpg

$ cygpath -w -a ./screenshot.jpg
C:\cygwin64\home\tony\screenshot.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows absolute paths always start with a drive letter, for example `C:\folder1\folder2\item.ext`. Cygwin absolute paths start with `/` - just like all UNIX/Linux filesystems - but provide a metafolder `cygdrive` that allows disparate Windows drive letters to be mapped seamlessly into the one filesystem tree, for example `/cygdrive/c/folder1/folder2/item.ext`. (In fact the two example file paths I've given would correspond to the same filesystem object.)

The fundamental problem here is that you have an invalid path. It's a relative path because it doesn't begin with `/`, but then it references what *looks like* an absolute path corresponding to a Windows drive letter and path:

> ```
> cygpath -w ./cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder/javafile.jar
> ```

What I think you probably meant was this, without the leading dot:

```
cygpath -w /cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder/javafile.jar
```

Fixing the quoting and generally tidying up, that would make your script segment look like this:

```
lockfile="$specialfolder/$passedargument.lock"
java -jar "$(cygpath -w /cygdrive/driveletter/folder/folder/javafile.jar)" -joption "$(cygpath -w "$lockfile")"
```